Compactly supported Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$
Definition :
If $\mu$ is any Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ then its support is defined as $$\text{supp}(\mu):=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d:\text{every open neighbourhood of }x\text{ has positive measure}\}. $$
I have a couple of questions regarding compactly supported measure, which I am not able to answer.
Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and assume that $\text{supp}(\mu)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
(Q-1) Can we say that $\mu$ is finite, i.e., $\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)<\infty$ ?
(Q-2) Can we say that $\mu(K)<\infty$ for every compact $K\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ ?
Any help/hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

If you define $\mu$ to be the borel measure on some compact set $K\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\mu(A)=0$ for every $A$ with $A\cap K=\varnothing$, then $\mu(K)<\infty$. It is always true that $\mu(K)<\infty$ where $\mu$ is the Borel measure and $K$ is compact by the Heine-Borel theorem.

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to (0,1)$ be a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ onto the open unit interval (obtained for example by playing around with the $\mathrm{tanh}$ function). Let $i \colon (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the natural inclusion. Let $\mu := (i \circ f)_*(\lambda)$ be the push-forward measure of the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ along $i \circ f$.
Then $\mathrm{supp}(\mu) = [0,1]$ is compact but $\mu([0,1]) = \infty$.
